# JList doesn't update for some reason

Tags: java, swing

There's a `Mainpanel` JFrame having  `Insert` and `View` as InternalJFrames. `Insert` inserts text data to .txt files (creates them if necessary) . `View` displays a list of .txt files in a JList which doesn't update , after exiting the application and running again the items are displayed correctly  , but I want to display the list as soon as I insert them.

**Expected Working** : After Writing to a .txt file from Insert IJFrame (this code works fine) and clicking a display button in `MainPanel` , the JList in `View` should display the item.

**What did I do?** : To tackle this I made a `updateValues()` method which re populates the JList but it still fails.

`MainPanel` :

```
public class MainPanel extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  View view;
  Insert insert;
  Read read;
  public MainPanel() {
    initComponents();
    pack();
    insert = new Insert();
    view = new View();
    read = new Read(view);
    jPanel2.add(insert);
    jPanel2.add(view);
    jPanel2.add(read);
    insert.setVisible(true); // Initally only insert in visible
    view.setVisible(false);  // later I've created buttons to 
    read.setVisible(false);  // display required IJFrame

}

private void readButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    read.updateValues();
    view.setVisible(false);
    insert.setVisible(false);
    read.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

`Read` :

```
public class Read extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

private View view;
public Read(View view) {
    initComponents();
    pack();
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    jList1.setModel(model);
    File folder = new File("/Naruto/Dattebayo/");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for(File file : listOfFiles ){
        if(file.getName().endsWith(".txt"))
        model.addElement(file.getName());

    }
    this.view=view;
}


public void updateValues() {
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    File folder = new File("/Naruto/Dattebatyo");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        if (file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            model.addElement(file.getName());
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never change the JList's model, and so it won't change it's display by magic, but will only change its display if you tell it to with your code. Your updateValues method creates a new DefaultListModel but then does nothing with it. Perhaps you should set the JList's model to be the new model by calling `setModel(model)` on the JList.

Key thing to note that the model variable in the two methods are two completely unique variables that refer to unique and separate objects. Changing the state of one will have absolutely no effect on the other. Again 1) call `jList1.setModel(model)` after creating your new model, 2) consider studying a decent book on OOPs concepts and Java programming because these concepts of variables, objects and variable scope is is fundamental stuff.

Comment: Thanks for you effort , I'am still a beginner there's a lot of stuff yet to learn :-)

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto, if Hovercraft Full Of Eels's (awesome name btw) answer helped you, you should consider accepting it.

Comment: @CristianMarian just curious , what does the name mean?

Comment: I don't know it if has any meaning, but the image of a hovercraft that is full of eels is just...something else